# Elasticsearch - Index word, bigram and trigram

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to index some phrases, like this :

```
"Elasticsearch is a great search engine"
```

indexed like

```
Elasticsearch       # word
is                  # word
a                   # word
great               # word
engine              # word
Elasticsearch is    # bi-gram
is a                # bi-gram
a great             # bi-gram
great search        # bi-gram
search engine       # bi-gram
Elasticsearch is a  # tri-gram
is a great          # tri-gram
a great search      # tri-gram
great search engine # tri-gram
```

I know how to index words (with default indexer) and to index bigrams and trigrams (with n-grams indexer), but not both at same time.

How can I do this ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [`multi-field` type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html). Here is an example of one I have created -

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
        },
        "my_metaphone": {
          "type": "phonetic",
          "encoder": "metaphone",
          "replace": false
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "synonym": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonym"
          ]
        },
        "metaphone": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "my_metaphone"
          ]
        },
        "porter": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "porter_stem"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "datafield": {
          "type": "multi_field",
          "store": "yes",
          "fields": {
            "datafield": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "simple"
            },
            "metaphone": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "metaphone"
            },
            "porter": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "porter"
            },
            "synonym": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "synonym"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then specify which field you want to search against, i.e. `datafield.synonym` or in your case `datafield.bigram`. You can then build your query up, boosting the fields as to which is most important to your results.